# Why does Drush Make usually skip large sections of my .make file with no errors or explanation?

Tags: drush

This [felt like a bug to me](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/549), but I was told it was technical support, so I'm asking here.

Running Drush 6.2 on OSX Mavericks, drush make usually skips most of our .make file for some unknown reason. If we keep running the command, eventually it works. The only difference in the output is the missing section.

Linux users running the same command (with the same .make file) are not seeing the same issue.

The command we are issuing is:
drush make --working-copy --no-core --no-cache -y -v --contrib-destination=. profilename.make

I don't feel like it's the .make file itself, because it works elsewhere.

Here's output with the --debug flag from a failed session (with the repo URL replaced), up to the point it checks out the first module.

```
Bootstrap to phase 0. [0 sec, 1.87 MB]                               [bootstrap]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drush() [0.01 sec, 1.99 MB] [bootstrap]
Cache HIT cid: 6.2.0-commandfiles-0-b2a725c613aec072d6594b2001dc5c79 [0.01 sec, 2 MB]                                                [debug]
Bootstrap to phase 0. [0.05 sec, 5.25 MB]                                                                                        [bootstrap]
Bootstrap to phase 0. [0.07 sec, 5.26 MB]                                                                                        [bootstrap]
Found command: make (commandfile=make) [0.07 sec, 5.26 MB]                                                                       [bootstrap]
Loading release_info engine. [0.11 sec, 5.28 MB]                                                                                    [notice]
Calling hook drush_make [0.11 sec, 5.38 MB]                                                                                          [debug]
Make new site in the current directory? (y/n): y
Beginning to build profilename.make. [0.12 sec, 5.66 MB]                                                                     [ok]
Backend invoke: /usr/bin/php  -d magic_quotes_gpc=Off -d magic_quotes_runtime=Off -d magic_quotes_sybase=Off                       [command]
/usr/local/Cellar/drush/6.2.0/libexec/drush.php --php=/usr/bin/php --php-options=' -d magic_quotes_gpc=Off -d
magic_quotes_runtime=Off -d magic_quotes_sybase=Off'  --backend=2  make-process /tmp/make_tmp_1395944498_53346c3280189 2>&1 [0.23
sec, 6.17 MB]
/usr/bin/php  -d magic_quotes_gpc=Off -d magic_quotes_runtime=Off -d magic_quotes_sybase=Off                                        [notice]
/usr/local/Cellar/drush/6.2.0/libexec/drush.php --php=/usr/bin/php --php-options=' -d magic_quotes_gpc=Off -d
magic_quotes_runtime=Off -d magic_quotes_sybase=Off'  --backend=2  make-process /tmp/make_tmp_1395944498_53346c3280189 2>&1 [0.23
sec, 6.18 MB]
Bootstrap to phase 0. [0.35 sec, 5.25 MB]                                                                                        [bootstrap]
Bootstrap to phase 0. [0.38 sec, 5.25 MB]                                                                                        [bootstrap]
Found command: make-process (commandfile=make) [0.38 sec, 5.25 MB]                                                               [bootstrap]
Loading release_info engine. [0.42 sec, 5.26 MB]                                                                                    [notice]
Calling hook drush_make_process [0.42 sec, 5.37 MB]                                                                                  [debug]
Returned from hook drush_make_process [0.42 sec, 5.37 MB]                                                                            [debug]
Command dispatch complete [0.42 sec, 5.35 MB]                                                                                       [notice]
Peak memory usage was 7.02 MB [0.42 sec, 5.34 MB]                                                                                   [memory]
Cache MISS cid: 6.2.0-alias-path--0df1237dd975a845493d7a49d0e0a21f [0.42 sec, 5.34 MB]                                               [debug]
Undefined property: DrushMakeProject_Library::$type make.project.inc:147 [0.43 sec, 5.7 MB]                                         [notice]
Executing: svn --force checkout https://repo.example.com/repos/wms/vendor/contrib/7.x/libraries/CAS/tags/1.3.2 /tmp/make_tmp_1395944498_53346c3280189/__build__/libraries/CAS
```

Here's output with the --debug flag from a successful session (with the repo URL replaced), up to the point it checks out the first module. Again, all we have to do is keep running the same command on the same make file, and it eventually works.

```
Bootstrap to phase 0. [0 sec, 1.87 MB]                               [bootstrap]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drush() [0.01 sec, 1.99 MB] [bootstrap]
Cache HIT cid: 6.2.0-commandfiles-0-b2a725c613aec072d6594b2001dc5c79 [0.01 sec, 2 MB]                                                [debug]
Bootstrap to phase 0. [0.05 sec, 5.25 MB]                                                                                        [bootstrap]
Bootstrap to phase 0. [0.08 sec, 5.26 MB]                                                                                        [bootstrap]
Found command: make (commandfile=make) [0.08 sec, 5.26 MB]                                                                       [bootstrap]
Loading release_info engine. [0.12 sec, 5.28 MB]                                                                                    [notice]
Calling hook drush_make [0.12 sec, 5.38 MB]                                                                                          [debug]
Make new site in the current directory? (y/n): y
Beginning to build profilename.make. [0.13 sec, 5.66 MB]                                                                     [ok]
Backend invoke: /usr/bin/php  -d magic_quotes_gpc=Off -d magic_quotes_runtime=Off -d magic_quotes_sybase=Off                       [command]
/usr/local/Cellar/drush/6.2.0/libexec/drush.php --php=/usr/bin/php --php-options=' -d magic_quotes_gpc=Off -d
magic_quotes_runtime=Off -d magic_quotes_sybase=Off'  --backend=2  make-process /tmp/make_tmp_1395944871_53346da723049 2>&1 [0.27
sec, 6.17 MB]
/usr/bin/php  -d magic_quotes_gpc=Off -d magic_quotes_runtime=Off -d magic_quotes_sybase=Off                                        [notice]
/usr/local/Cellar/drush/6.2.0/libexec/drush.php --php=/usr/bin/php --php-options=' -d magic_quotes_gpc=Off -d
magic_quotes_runtime=Off -d magic_quotes_sybase=Off'  --backend=2  make-process /tmp/make_tmp_1395944871_53346da723049 2>&1 [0.27
sec, 6.18 MB]
Bootstrap to phase 0. [0.43 sec, 6 MB]                                                                                           [bootstrap]
Bootstrap to phase 0. [0.46 sec, 6 MB]                                                                                           [bootstrap]
Found command: make-process (commandfile=make) [0.46 sec, 6 MB]                                                                  [bootstrap]
Loading release_info engine. [0.5 sec, 6.02 MB]                                                                                     [notice]
Calling hook drush_make_process [0.5 sec, 6.12 MB]                                                                                   [debug]
navigation404 svn --force checkout %s %s from                                                                                    [ok]
https://repo.example.com/repos/wms/vendor/contrib/7.x/modules/navigation404/tags/7.x-1.0. [1.02 sec, 6.15 MB]
```

It then checks out all the modules the failed build missed.

Just as we get to the point where the failed build starts, in the successful build we see the same messages:

```
Returned from hook drush_make_process [200.02 sec, 7.01 MB]                                                                          [debug]
Command dispatch complete [200.02 sec, 6.99 MB]                                                                                     [notice]
Peak memory usage was 7.71 MB [200.02 sec, 6.98 MB]                                                                                 [memory]
Cache MISS cid: 6.2.0-alias-path--0df1237dd975a845493d7a49d0e0a21f [200.02 sec, 7 MB]                                                [debug]
Undefined property: DrushMakeProject_Library::$type make.project.inc:147 [200.05 sec, 5.97 MB]                                      [notice]
Executing: svn --force checkout https://repo.example.com/repos/wms/vendor/contrib/7.x/libraries/CAS/tags/1.3.2 /tmp/make_tmp_1395944871_53346da723049/__build__/libraries/CAS
```

Any ideas on how to make it succeed all the time? Any more info I can give?

**Edit:** [here's a (URL-replaced) copy of the .make file](https://docs.google.com/document/d/19tdtWiVVKOyF9yH2uNFhWCQNzaEbdkZyoODUsJ_BBTk/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Can you post your Make file by chance?

Comment: @Steven edited my post; it's at the end.

Comment: I don't know if this is helpful in diagnosing the issue, but today my make file absolutely refused to do anything other than skip straight to the libraries. I split my make file into multiple files, and each built successfully. So maybe it's something to do with the size of the make file?

Comment: I've also been told by a colleague that this has happened to him occasionally in Linux, but it's a rare event for him instead of a constant occurrence like it is for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kept coming back to this question while running Drush 6 on a mac.
In the meantime it seems there is an answer on the original bug post: update to Drush 7 or greater.
See: https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/549#issuecomment-101353376 and https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/pull/1049
I'm doing fine now with Drush 8.0.1.

Comment: Drush 7 was the answer for me in the end as well (at the time this was originally posted, Drush 7 wasn't final).